# How to determine the time at which a blob lease was acquired

Tags: azure

I am obtaining **infinite** leases on blobs, but would want to be able to determine how 'old' any such lease might be. i.e. when was it originally acquired? Is there a away to determine this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently it's not possible through the API. You would need to maintain that separately. One possibility could be to save this information in blob's metadata. When you acquire the lease, you get the date/time and then save that as one of the blob's metadata.